# Cloudscraper returns AttributeError: 'SSLContext' object has no attribute 'orig_wrap_socket'

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, python-requests, sslcontext

```
import cloudscraper
import requests

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()  # returns a CloudScraper instance
# Or: scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()  # CloudScraper inherits from requests.Session
print (scraper.get("https://www.youtube.com/").text )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-459-1f19dc044105> in <module>
      2 import requests
      3 
----> 4 scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()  # returns a CloudScraper instance
      5 # Or: scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()  # CloudScraper inherits from requests.Session
      6 print (scraper.get("https://www.youtube.com/").text )

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudscraper/__init__.py in create_scraper(cls, sess, **kwargs)
    315         Convenience function for creating a ready-to-go CloudScraper object.
    316         
--> 317         scraper = cls(**kwargs)
    318 
    319         if sess:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudscraper/__init__.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    169                 server_hostname=self.server_hostname,
    170                 source_address=self.source_address,
--> 171                 ssl_context=self.ssl_context
    172             )
    173         )

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudscraper/__init__.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     75             self.ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
     76 
---> 77             self.ssl_context.orig_wrap_socket = self.ssl_context.wrap_socket
     78             self.ssl_context.wrap_socket = self.wrap_socket
     79 

AttributeError: 'SSLContext' object has no attribute 'orig_wrap_socket'
```

The code was run according to the documentation on https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/ and I cant find relevant supporting information on how to solve this error message.

Comment: Make sure that the following packages are up to date:
`Requests >= 2.9.2`
`Requests_toolbelt >= 0.9.1`
as described here https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/ under the dependencies heading.
I hope this helps!

Comment: @Eiri, Unfortunately, updating the packages had no positive effect, the same error message prevails.

Comment: Can you please try using *python3.7*?

Comment: @Eiri, sadly somehow my pipenv fails with python3.7. But got the same error on python 3.6 and working well on python3.8.

Comment: I can confirm python 3.8 works, bypassing cloudflare :)

Comment: Any way to fix the code to be compatible with python 3.6 or lower? I am too unfamiliar with the architecture there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My scripts is working well until the latest version `1.2.60` release 12 days ago. Maybe is the problem with the old library `ssl.py` in python`3.6`.

Here are my temporally solution:

- use the last version `1.2.58`: `pip3 install cloudscraper==1.2.58`
- or using python `3.7+`, tested working with python 3.7